# How To Bind Select Option to Input Field

Tags: angular, binding, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to get a value from a select option to bind to an input field and that value populates my form property in my reactive form.  Here is my code:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  templateUrl: 'main.html',
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  
  @ViewChild('templates') templates !: ElementRef
  optionChoice: any = '';
  taxonomyResponse: any = {
    categoryList: [
      {
        name: 'Option 1',
      },
      {
        name: 'Option 2',
      },
      {
        name: 'Option 3',
      },
    ],
  };

  form!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  selectForm = this.fb.group({
    selectOption: ''
  })

  onChange() {
    this.optionChoice = this.templates.nativeElement.value;
    console.log(this.optionChoice)
  }

  submit() {
    console.log(this.selectForm.value);
  }

}


bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Here is my HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="selectForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <select id="dropdown" class="form-select" #templates (change)="onChange()">
    <option>Please Select Option</option>
    <option *ngFor="let t of taxonomyResponse.categoryList">{{t.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" formControlName="selectOption" value="{{optionChoice}}" />
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to be able to take the value from the selected option, bind it to the input field and display the value on my form property.  I know that I am missing one part, I just can't figure it out.

Here is a link to [Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-e4mmhz?file=src%2Fmain.html)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `value` attribute in this case.

```
<input type="text" formControlName="selectOptions" />
```

Instead, you should iterate each `FormGroup` in the `options` FormArray and set the value to the `selectOption` FormControl via `patchValue` method.

```
onChange() {
  this.optionChoice = this.templates.nativeElement.value;
  console.log(this.optionChoice);

  for (let i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++) {
    (this.options.controls[i] as FormGroup).controls.selectOptions.patchValue(
      this.optionChoice,
      { emitEvent: false }
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fmtydq?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the formControlName to the select in order to bind the form with the control. Without the formControlName, angular does not know that your html should be part of the form.
Change your html to:

```
<select id="dropdown" class="form-select" #templates formControlName="selectOption" 
    (change)="onChange()">
    <option>Please Select Option</option>
    <option *ngFor="let t of taxonomyResponse.categoryList">{{t.name}}</option></select>
```

Comment: I'm looking to bind the select option to the input text field

Comment: This will take the value from the select and change the input to display the selected option. They are bound, in that when you change your selection in the select, the input changes too. Do you intend them to work differently?

Comment: Hi @Ethan. I've updated my Stack Blitz to give you a better understanding of what I mean.  The select option is not part of the form group info that gets submitted to an API. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-e4mmhz?file=src%2Fmain.html)[/link]